# SOS Job Scheduler Email Alert Issue (Windows)

Tags: scheduling, jobs, job-scheduling

Not sure how many of you used SOS Job Scheduler before but i'm having issues sending out error alert emails.
I captured the log below of the problem i've been having and also provided a link for reference.

http://www.sos-berlin.com/doc/en/scheduler.doc/email.xml

```
`2013-07-28 22:44:27.671+0800 [WARN] SCHEDULER-302 Error sending e-mail: Z-JAVA-105 Java exception javax.mail.internet.AddressException("Empty address"), method=set [from= ....
`
```

My factory.ini settings are below:

```
`html_dir = ${SCHEDULER_HOME}/operations_gui
mail_on_error = yes
mail_on_warning = yes
mail_on_success = yes
mail_on_process = no
log_mail_from = abc@gmail.com
log_mail_to = edf@hotmail.com
log_mail_cc =
log_mail_bcc =
smtp = smtp.gmail.com
mail_queue_dir = ${SCHEDULER_DATA}/mail
mail.smtp.user = abc@gmail.com
mail.smtp.password = xxxxxx
mail.smtp.port = 587
mail.smtp.starttls.required = true`
```

Has anyone come across this issue before ? I'm out of ideas so if anybody can point me in the right direction it would be much obliged.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you hit bug #JS-987 described here: [JobScheduler cannot send email](http://www.sos-berlin.com/jira/browse/JS-987).